# How to get both a number and character from the user?

Tags: c, user-input, tokenize

There are two variables `a` and `b`, and I want to get data from the user. The data can be a number from `1` to `1000` or `#`,  and they should be apart by a space.

So how to get this kind of input from the user?

Comment: Please chose a language

Comment: What? I mean C lang

Comment: You tagged it both C and C++.

Comment: both of them are OK,

Comment: @laoqiren You'll be lambasted for saying either or, mostly because they're two totally different languages.

Comment: OK, I see, now I just mean C, thanks a lot

Comment: @laoqiren Please edit your Question with more details. What should be the Input/output ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, this is too broad a scenario to provide exact *answer*. However, I'll be happy to provide you the idea.

- Read user input using [`fgets()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets).
- Tokenize the input using delimiter (space, here) by [`strtok()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok).
- Use appropriate converter functions (*example: [`strtol()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strtol)*) to check and convert the inputs.

Now choose a language, write the code and come back if you have any specific issue / question to be addressed / answered.

Comment: What difficult? Did you even try? It's not so hard once you start, give it a try.

Comment: Oh, I mean I think there should be another more simple solution because this problem is from a test which is very simple.  So, so how will a so difficult solution to solve a so easy test? Oh, I'm so sad

Comment: `Oh, I'm so sad` Wait until you get married.

Comment: @laoqiren - you could go for `sscanf` instead of `strtok` and `strtol` if you find that easier. Just did it using less than 10 lines of code. Give it a try. If you can't make it work, you can ask a question where you post the code that doesn't work.